# Negative values in radio flux maps?

Tags: astronomy

I am trying to understand some maps of radio emission in e.g the Milky Way. I continue to see in papers that these radio maps report negative values of the flux in Jansky units, although no explanation is given as to why.

For example Figure 1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.10541.pdf and here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.02695.pdf
[image]
I am wondering if the negative values are simply due to background subtraction, or if there is something more complicated going on.

If it's just background subtraction, a simple reference explainaing how the background subtraction is done in general would be useful.

Comment: Please link to arXiv abstract pages rather than PDF files. You might also consider making the visible text of your link some human-useful information about the reference, such as its author, title, or year, instead of just its arXiv telephone number.

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering if the negative values are simply due to background subtraction, or if there is something more complicated going on.

In fact, there are a lot of complicated things going on here.
You have provided links to two papers that rely on interferometric observations from the Very Large Array (VLA), and MeerKAT.

VLA and MeerKAT are astronomical interferometers, *i.e.* telescope arrays acting together as one single virtual telescope. This implies a specific process of imaging, which is (mainly) responsible for the negative values in your maps.

This gif shows how sky images are produced by arrays of telescopes thanks to aperture synthesis:

[image: Aperture synthesis]

During the first part of the gif, we are only adding more telescopes to the uv plane (which represents the ground on which telescopes are positioned), then the rotation of the sky takes care of the rest.

Since the sky image is sampled by a fringe pattern, we are bound to  have artifacts and negative values in the final map, although this is minimized by adding more telescopes to the uv plane. And there are also algorithms that are supposed to "clean" (reconstruct) the map.

In the papers that you linked, the authors quickly mention the process of cleaning:

> Natural weighting was employed in the CASA task tclean to recover the best signal/noise ratio possible at the expense of resolution.

> All imaging was done using wsclean (Offringa et al. 2014) with multiscale cleaning (Offringa & Smirnov 2017) enabled, and a Briggs (1995) robust value of −1.5, to provide high (∼4′′) angular resolution and suppress the sidelobes of the synthesised beam.

There are many techniques used to clean an interferometric map, including iterative algorithms, and/or using a source model.

Depending on the signal-to-noise ratio of the observations, on the size and configuration of the array, and  on the quality of the cleaning procedure, an interferometric maps can contain a lot of negative values, such as in your example.

Lastly, an other important parameter is the use of short-spacings observations. When using an interferometer (such as ALMA), we are mainly sampling high-resolution features, since the interferometer acts as a filter that ignores small spatial frequencies.
That is why it is useful to combine an interferometric map with a single-dish map, obtained with a regular radio telescope, such as the IRAM-30m.

Using short-spacings observations would probably enhance the map that you showed. Here is an example :

[image: Short spacings, Goicoechea et al. 2016]

Here are some useful references on interferometry, aperture synthesis, cleaning, etc:

[A Sightseeing Tour of mm Interferometry (Jérôme Pety)](https://web-archives.iram.fr/IRAMFR/IS/IS2006/presentations/pety-061002.pdf)

[Radio-astronomy Interferometry - Introduction (Philippe Salomé)](https://philippe-salome.obspm.fr/files/2016/01/lecture.pdf)

A mathematical approach to interferometry and cleaning:

[Principles of image reconstruction in
Interferometry (Éric Thiébaut)](https://www.edp-open.org/images/stories/books/fulldl/eas_59/eas59_pp157-187.pdf)

And here is a book recommendation: [Tools of Radioastronomy](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-39950-3)

Comment: interesting, but I'm not convinced this correctly explains the negative values seen in the maps. For example in Fig 1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.10541.pdf , there are contiguous regions of negative values. This does not look like some dips in an interference pattern to me - it looks like there are not many bright sources in that region, and the brightness is simply below the median intensity of the image.

Comment: further,  Further, in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.02695.pdf , it is noted ":  For the background subtraction, we masked the
sources and calculated the median intensity of the image. We then multiplied the median background intensity by the
number of beam areas for the source to find a background flux density"

Comment: Well if that helps, there is also the very simple fact that any real observation is characterized by some form of noise, often gaussian and centered on zero. Interference dips would explain the darker patches that are correlated to the sources, and gaussian noise may cause the more diffuse negative values. We can even guesstimate a 0.02 mJy/beam standard deviation for the gaussian noise in your image.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I'm confused about the Gaussian noise comment. Sure, a non-interferometric telescope has noise too, but the noise is some positive addition to the source brightness giving the observed signal.The noise is typically shot noise which is not gaussian. So I don't see how noise can give negative values.

Comment: No, in fact radio receivers are dominated by random noise, since they are not sensitive to individual photons but to the power $P=kT\Delta \nu$ of the incident EM wave (using either a bolometer or a SIS junction). For a faint source, the signal is completely dominated by the contributions from atmospheric emission, ground temperature and receiver temperature.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but I still don't understand, deposited power should be be positive, how can the P in your above comment be negative? Atmospheric emission and reciever temperature etc should only increase the measured flux, not produce negative values. Perhaps you can direct me to a reference explaining how noise can give negative flux.

Comment: Deposited power is physically positive but the signal stored in the data can be negative with respect to the baseline of your spectral observations. Please have a look at these low signal-to-noise radio spectra for example : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.8158.pdf (in Fig. 1 and Fig. 2). The "baseline" is the horizontal line centered on zero. It is entirely possible (and common) to have negative pixels in low signal-to-noise/empty areas of radio maps, when negative fluctuations around the baseline are larger than positive fluctuations.